# AJAX response from IE9 contains invalid characters

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I am getting a significantly different JSON response in IE9 and am not certain where things are falling apart:

My JS (this is using jquery form- http://malsup.com/jquery/form/):

```
var self = this,
                options = {
                    beforeSubmit: this.beforeSubmit,
                    uploadProgress: this.uploadProgress,
                    success: this.uploadSuccess,
                    resetForm: true
                },
                form = $(this.forms.addNewDocument);

        $(form).ajaxSubmit(options);
```

I am logging the response from within `uploadSuccess`.

In my PHP, before using `json_encode`, the response I am getting is:

```
array(2) {
 ["values"]=&gt;
 array(1) {
   ["categoryId"]=&gt;
   string(1) "1"
 }
 ["template"]=&gt;
 array(1) {
   ["body"]=&gt;
   string(211) "<li id="18"><span class="doc-title">test4.txt</span>&nbsp;<span class="doc-    date">9/30/2014</span>&nbsp;<span class="doc-user">Ling Chow</span><i class="fa fa-download"></i><i class="fa fa-times-circle"></i></li>"
 }
}
```

Then when I wrap the array in `json_encode($myresult)` and I log the ajax response I get the following:

```
In IE 9
 {"values":{"categoryId":"1"},"template":{"body":"<li id='\"6\"'><span class='\"doc-    title\"'>test.txt&lt;\/span&gt;&nbsp;<span class='\"doc-date\"'>9\/30\/2014&lt;\/span&gt;&nbsp;<span class='\"doc-user\"'>Ling Chow&lt;\/span&gt;<i class='\"fa' fa-download\?="">&lt;\/i&gt;<i class='\"fa' fa-times-circle\?="">&lt;\/i&gt;&lt;\/li&gt;"}}</i></i></span></span></span></li>

In IE10/Chrome
{"values":{"categoryId":"1"},"template":{"body":"<li id=\"9\"><span class=\"doc-title\">accredmaster2.html<\/span>&nbsp;<span class=\"doc-date\">9\/30\/2014<\/span>&nbsp;<span class=\"doc-user\">Ling Chow<\/span><i class=\"fa fa-download\"><\/i><i class=\"fa fa-times-circle\"><\/i><\/li>"}}
```

IE9 is adding a lot of single quotes, a "?=" in there, and it looks like it's ending the JSON early. Why is this happening, and why specific to IE9?

Answer (score 0):

Use `header('content-type: application/json');` before `json_encode` in your php.  That'll let IE9 realize you're returning json and won't try to escape everything.

Comment: When I add "header('content-type: application/json');" before the json_encode, IE prompts me to save the  JSON response as a file. the JSON in that file is the correct formatting, but I need to be able to send data back to my javascript instead of downloading?

Comment: IE is asking you to download something, from an ajax request? are you sure in IE9 it's sending an ajax request rather than submitting the form?

Comment: Yes, I am certain IE9 is sending an ajax request, but it looks like it doesn't know what to do with the content type so it just asks me to save the response.